# How do you implement "show" tail-recursively?

Tags: haskell, tail-recursion

Haskell's `show` is usually implemented recursively as:

```
data Tree = Node Tree Tree | Leaf

show' (Node left right) = "(Node " ++ show' left ++ " " ++ show' right ++ ")"
show' Leaf              = "Leaf"

main = putStrLn $ show' (Node (Node Leaf Leaf) Leaf)
```

How can you implement `show` using tail recursion?

Comment: I'm interested in wether there is an obvious translation of non-tail-recursive functions with multiple recursive branches to their tail-recursive counterparts. Am I wrong in thinking that you would have to use zippers in order to keep it efficient, since the accumulating structure needs to be edited deeply on each tail call?

Comment: CPS essentially makes the accumulating structure a function, which is powerful enough to be "edited deeply"

Comment: Ah, okay! That fits it, thanks guys.

Comment: Doesn't Haskell's `showsPrec` solve exactly this problem by getting you to provide a function `a -> ShowS` given a precedence? Not sure, but that's what I thought?

Comment: @Alec `showsPrec` is more efficient than `show`, but it isn't tail recursive. However, that's because in Haskell, it doesn't make *sense* for `show` to be tail recursive (ref. luqui's mention of corecursivity).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using CPS, as mentioned by M. Shaw.

```
show' :: Tree -> String
show' = \tree -> go tree id
    where
    go (Node left right) c = 
      go left (\l -> go right (\r -> c ("(Node " ++ l ++ " " ++ r ++ ")")))
    go Leaf c = c "Leaf"
```

It's important to keep in mind that Haskell's laziness obviates the need for tail recursion in many cases.  In this case, the tail recursive version has to traverse the entire tree before any part of the input can be returned.  Try showing an infinite tree with each version.  When returning a lazy structure such as `String` in a lazy language, it is better to be corecursive (which your original implementation is) than tail recursive.

Most of the time of this function will be eaten up by left-nested `(++)` calls, which is `O(n)` in its left argument.  The solution is to use a [difference list](https://wiki.haskell.org/Difference_list), which is a form of continuation-passing style itself.

See also [Continuation-Based Program Transformation Strategies](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.83.8567), which talks about how to arrive at efficient algorithms by converting to CPS, then transforming the structure of the continuations into something more concrete to arrive at a tail-recursive solution.

Answer (score 4):

You can turn this tail-recursive via [Continuation passing style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style). Have a look the examples on the wiki page.